# Predictable behaviour of overlapping Socket.BeginSend / EndSend calls

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Say, I have a class, that wraps a Socket and (in addition to other things) performs asynchronous sends of data.

I perform the send in the following way (greatly abbreviated - no error handling etc etc):

```
private Socket _socket;

public void Write(byte[] data, Action callback)
{
    _socket.BeginSend(
        data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None,
        new AsyncCallback(WriteMaybeDone),
        new { Data = data, SentSoFar = 0, Callback = callback}
    )
}

public void WriteMaybeDone(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int bytesSent = _socket.EndSend(ar);
    var state = ar.AsyncState;
    state.SentSoFar += bytesSent;
    if (state.SentSoFar < state.Data.Length) {
        _socket.BeginSend(
            data, state.SentSoFar, State.Data.Length - state.SentSoFar,
            SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(WriteMaybeDone), state
        );
    } else {
        if (state.Callback != null) {
            state.Callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Here we ensure, that all data is sent, before the passed callback is called.

How can one ensure, that "overlapping" calls to Write behave in a predictable manner? Especially since the callback, that is passed to BeginSend might be called before all data is sent. I need to ensure, that the data, that is passed to a call to Write goes to the wire *not* interleaved with data, that is passed to subsequent Write calls, that are made before the callback for the first Write is fired.

I am constrained to .NET 3.5

Comment: If you have access to .NET framework 4.5, I'd recommend using the await/async syntax instead. You can then use continuations to ensure everything is sent in order etc. - you'd just use `SendAsync` instead of `BeginSend`, and if you do all the sending in some cycle or something, await/async is extremely easy to use and it will ensure that your CPU-bound work doesn't get blocked by I/O-bound work until absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Luaan Yes, I understand that, but I am constrained to .NET 3.5 (mentioned it in the edit).

Comment: What makes you think that the callback, that is passed to BeginSend might be called before all data is sent? The documentation on the [Asynchronous Programming Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm) clearly states: "The first of these defines an AsyncCallback delegate that references a method that is called **when the asynchronous operation completes**." And even when it would be called, `int bytesSent = _socket.EndSend(ar);` blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only start the next send operation after the previous completed. You could enqueue the data to be sent, or use a signaling mechanism (like `AsyncSemaphore` or `TaskCompletionSource`) to notify the next write that the previous is done.

In other words, use a producer-consumer design pattern. The producers are the operations that want to write. The single consumer is a thread or async workflow that does the physical writes one after the other.

Comment: That's one thing I've considered. Do you, perhaps, happen to know if NetworkStream.BeginWrite / EndWrite will do that for me? That would *kinda* make sense, since EndWrite does not return a number of bytes written (which means, there are no partial writes). The question is whether or not it is safe to do multiple BeginWrite calls without waiting for them to complete first.

Comment: Reflector shows that Socket.BeginSend does not do that. It calls WSASend in a straight-forward way. I could not find out whether WSASend guarantees order for multiple overlapped send operations. Without that guarantee given, I'd not risk it.

Comment: That's the same. It does nothing by itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. At least now I know, that I am not doing useless work when I'll actually implement queueing / buffering in my code.